# How to insert data in column based on data from other two column in mysql

Tags: mysql, case

I have 3 columns on table named loan.

first column named approved_by_asm which holds integer value 0,1 or 2

second column named approved_by_rsm which holds integer value 0,1 or 2

and third column named status.

```sql
WHEN approved_by_asm=1 AND approved_by_rsm=0 THEN  status is 'PENDING'
WHEN approved_by_asm=0 AND approved_by_rsm=0 THEN  status is 'PENDING'
WHEN approved_by_asm=0 AND approved_by_rsm=0 THEN  status is 'PENDING'
WHEN approved_by_asm=1 AND approved_by_rsm=1 THEN  status is 'APPROVED'
ELSE status 'DECLINED'
```

How to do this using SQL? Here is my code

```
public void setStatus(){

try{

 Connection con = DBConn.myConn();

String str= outletOwner_jTextField.getText();

PreparedStatement s1 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT approved_by_asm FROM 
loan_coooler WHERE outlet_owner=?");

s1.setString(1, str);

ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery();


PreparedStatement s2 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT approved_by_rsm FROM 
loan_coooler WHERE outlet_owner=?");

s1.setString(1, str);

ResultSet rs2 = s2.executeQuery();


Statement s3 = con.createStatement("INSERT INTO loan_coooler(status) VALUES(
CASE  WHEN s1=1 AND s2=0 THEN 'PENDING'

WHEN s1=0 AND s2=1 THEN 'PENDING'

WHEN s1=0 AND s2=0 THEN 'PENDING'

WHEN s1=1 AND s2=1 THEN 'APPROVED'

ELSE 'DECLINED');

int rs3 = s3.executeUpdate();

}

catch (Exception ex) { 

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex, ex.getMessage(), WIDTH, null);

        }
}
```

Comment: 1) Read [MySQL User Manual : CASE operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) carefully. You need in 2nd form of operator (not `CASE status WHEN` but `CASE WHEN`, and finalizing `END` is lost); 2) MySQL have no predefined constants named `PENDING` and `APPROVED`; 3) MySQL server knows nothing about `s1` and `s2` statements which exists in program code;

Comment: Does `outlet_owner` field is defined as UNIQUE in `approved_by_asm` by according index (problem #5)? and the problem #3 remains non-corrected.

Comment: outlet_owner is UNIQUE, no duplicate @Akina si and s2 i used as variable value which stores results of SQL for determining value of status column.

Comment: *outlet_owner is UNIQUE, no duplicate* One more time - does the UNIQUE index by `outlet_owner` field exists in table structure? if not then the field is NOT unique, even it is stored unique by client-side logic. *si and s2 i used as variable value which stores results of SQL for determining value of status column.* They are 1) recordsets 2) unknown to MySQL server.

Comment: One more - why you INSERT? maybe you need to alter the record with `outlet_owner` value obtained from `outletOwner_jTextField.getText()`? if so you need to UPDATE the existing record, not INSERT new one (with all fields empty except `status`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store data that can be [easily] *derived* from other bits of data in the same record.

Would you store **age** (which needs updating each and every day) or **date_of_birth** (from which you can *calculate* age)?

Create a view that calculates the status as and when you need it:

```
create view view1 
as 
select 
  approved_by_asm
, approved_by_rsm
, case 
  when approved_by_asm = 0 and approved_by_rsm = 0 THEN 'PENDING'
  when approved_by_asm = 0 and approved_by_rsm = 1 THEN 'PENDING'
  when approved_by_asm = 1 and approved_by_rsm = 0 THEN 'PENDING'
  when approved_by_asm = 1 and approved_by_rsm = 1 THEN 'APPROVED'
  else 'DECLINED' 
  end status 
from table1 ;
```

Comment: It solved my problem, bu i don't understand what those comma are doing?

Comment: They're separating the select'ed fields from one another! 
OK, I have the slightly "odd" habit of putting them at the /start/ of a line instead of "hidden away" at the end.  Call it one of my foibles, but I've yet to come across /any/ language that can start a statement with a comma so seeing one in my "code" *has* to be a continuation of something that came before.